# Создать белый список URL'ов

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разрешать пользователю заходить только на определенные URL'ы с любого браузера для ОС Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS?

Comment: в заголовке ip-адреса. в тексте url-ы. вы не знаете, что это разные сущности? начните хотя бы со статей в википедии.

Comment: Я знаю что это разные сущности. Мне нужен аналог файла Hosts как в Windows.

Comment: Эти сущности "живут" рядом друг с другом. По доменному имени мы получаем ip-адрес. Это происходит при помощи DNS.

Comment: 1. ну вообще-то это в ms/windows сделали аналог файла `/etc/hosts`, используемого в unix. всё-таки не стоит пренебрегать [википедией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts). 2. да и про [url](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) почитайте обязательно.

Comment: Спасибо за столь ценные советы. Раз Вы хорошо знаете про адресацию в сети интернет, может и ответ подскажете?

Comment: ваш вопрос слишком глобален. а для схемы (например) https — вообще не имеет решения без дополнительных ограничений.

Comment: Неужели нельзя создать такой "белый список адресов" в Ubuntu? Ведь существуют функции ограничения доступа в интернете. Например, родительский контроль у Касперского, хождение в интернет через прокси-сервер, фильтрация URL в настройках роутера.

Comment: *Неужели нельзя создать такой "белый список адресов" в Ubuntu?* — его **нигде** нельзя создать. то, что вы дальше перечисляете, вновь показывает, что вы не понимаете разницы между url и ip-адресом. либо ждите того, кто разложит по полочкам ту кашу, которая у вас сейчас в голове по данному поводу, либо разгребите её самостоятельно. и тогда приходите с **корректно** сформулированным вопросом. удачи!

Comment: Ну так объясните по полочкам в ответе. Если бы я всё знал — я бы тогда и не спрашивал. Напишите то, что вы понимаете по разницей между ip и url. В моём представлении ip-адрес это уникальный идентификатор устройства подключенного к сети, а url это ссылка на этот идентификатор. Вы же, наверное, понимаете смысл моего вопроса. Скажите, что я не так спрашиваю.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на эту утилиту:

> Privoxy is a web proxy with advanced filtering capabilities for
>   protecting privacy, filtering web page content, managing cookies,
>   controlling access, and removing ads, banners, pop-ups and other
>   obnoxious Internet junk. Privoxy has a very flexible configuration and
>   can be customized to suit individual needs and tastes. Privoxy has
>   application for both stand-alone systems and multi-user networks.